# Correct probability with XGBoost in R

Tags: r, probability, boosting

It seems that I don't understand results of XGBoost. I've made a model with one variable and
a binary target variable, and only one tree.

Sample of data structure is presented below.

```
head(table(variable, target))

        target
variable     0     1
       1 21418  3020
       2 76210  8382
       3 14705  2317
       4 20610  2941
       5  5234   830
       6  6775   981
```

Estimation and predictions:

```
model <- xgboost(
  data = variable,
  label = target,
  nrounds = 1,
  objective = "binary:logistic",
  max_depth=4,
)

prob <- predict(model, newdata=variable)
head(cbind(count = table(variable),
      target = tapply(target, variable, mean),  
      prob= tapply(prob, variable, mean)))
```

gives

```
[1] train-logloss:0.538983 
  count     target      prob
1 24438 0.12357803 0.3889727
2 84592 0.09908738 0.3819989
3 17022 0.13611796 0.3925620
4 23551 0.12487792 0.3900587
5  6064 0.13687335 0.3900587
6  7756 0.12648272 0.3900587
```

As I read in documentation, result of xgboost should be probability, but as we can see above, it's far from that.

Moreover, looking at the tree, there are all observations for which variable==1 in the first leaf. So calculating probability in this leaf as fraction of target==1, should give 0.12. As it is't, then what is it?

[image: XGBoost Tree]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What doesn’t look like a probability to you?

Comment: @Dave In fact, my formulation wasn't precise enough. I wanted to say that that model estimates, which should be probability of belonging to class 1, are too far from empirical values, according to my current understanding.

Comment: Do you mean that the `prob` and `target` columns differ by too much?

Comment: Yes. But I understand now why.

Comment: Is your `variable` a factor with six levels (categories), each of which has some combination of zeros and ones?

Comment: There are more levels, table is truncated. And table shown is an aggregate. `target` has values 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XGBoost applies a *learning rate*: the value (in log-odds) in a leaf is scaled by this learning rate compared to the tree-building mechanism.
If you set the learning rate to 1, you will recover predicted probabilities closer to the empirical ones.

There is further shrinkage from the regularization parameters. And if this weren't binary classification, you'd have to account for the base score. Finally, the nonlinearity of the sigmoid will cause some slight mismatch between the average log-odds and average outcome.

(All of this is washed out by having more iterations.)

Comment: Your answer helped me with understanding documentation. It's clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: @Michal: If this answer is helpful to you, you could upvote and if it solves the issue you had, you could even accept it as the solution.

Comment: My reputation is too low to upvote, but I accepted it. Thank you for pointing that out.